# Kill mediaplayer in an Activity after returning from Settings Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-mediaplayer, lifecycle

I'm new to Android. I'm doing my first app. I have an ActivityMain and I go to the Preferences Fragment where I have an option to enable or disable music. After I change my preferences and press Ok the fragment closes and I want to check if the user has put "No" on the music option and in that case kill the mediaplayer. Where should I do this. I put that in onResume but it doesn't work. Where should I put my code to trigger the killMusic() method after returning from the fragment??

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    music = pref.getString("music", null);
    if (music.equals("No")){
        killMusic();
    }
}


private void killMusic() {
    if (introSong != null) {
        introSong.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: `onResume` sounds like a good place to put it...

Comment: it doesn't work.....I've already tried it. And the killMusic method works fine....

Comment: when I choose in the fragment "music"-->"No" in the settings and I restart the app there's no music so the method works fine....but I want it to stop the music without having to restart the app....the onResume method doesn't seem to be the place to put the method once the fragment is closed and you return to the activity to check if the user has put no on music and kill it.......

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put down some log message to be able to check if your method is called, like :

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("DEBUG","MyClass::onResume called");
    music = pref.getString("music", null);
    if (music.equals("No")){
        killMusic();
    }
}
```

That being said, is your code in the onResume of some fragment, or of the activity ? Because your Preference is a fragment, and thus it is called without pausing/resuming the main activity. That could explain why you code is not working/called...

Comment: the code is in the onResume of the activity, what I want to achieve is
Activity->touch on preferences button on action bar->preferences fragment open->select preferences and press ok on fragment-->fragment closes->when I'm back into the activity, kill the music if the user has put "Music" option in "No"
Now it's working but I have to restart the application for the changes to be applied. Also the shared Preferences are working fine, if I restart the application the preferences are on the same state as before closing it the last time.....